# Relationship between a TypeScript class and an interface with the same name

Tags: class, typescript, interface

I'm having a bit of trouble locating any clear documentation or explanation for the seemingly-special relationship between a TypeScript class and an interface with the same name.

- What's the significance of an interface with the same name as a class?
- Why does a class that shares its name with an interface implement that interface automatically?
- Why does the compiler complain about my getter implementation of a readonly interface field when the class and interface have the same name, but accept the implementation if the names are different?
- Is there any canonical documentation addressing these questions?

Code:

```
// Co-named interface and class doesn't like readonly property implementation:

interface Foo {
  readonly x: number; // Error: Duplicate identifier 'x'
  y: number;
}

class Foo {
  get x(): number { // Error: Duplicate identifier 'x'
    return 0;
  }

  y = 1;
}

// Same as above, but different class name + explicit `implements`

class Bar implements Foo {
  get x(): number { // No error!
    return 0;
  }

  y = 1;
}

// Duplicating the first example, but explicitly implementing the co-named interface:

interface Baz {
  readonly x: number; // Error: Duplicate identifier 'x'
  y: number;
}

class Baz implements Baz {
  get x(): number { // Error: Duplicate identifier 'x'
    return 0;
  }

  y = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Interfaces of the same name within a module [will be merged](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces):

```
interface Foo {
    x: number;
}

interface Foo {
    y: string;
}

let g = {} as Foo;
g.x; // OK
g.y; // OK
```

A class declaration creates [both a constructor function as well as type declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#using-a-class-as-an-interface), which essentially means that all classes can be used as interfaces.

```
class Bar {
    y: number;
}

interface IBaz extends Bar { } // includes y: number

class CBaz implements Bar {
    y: number = 5;
}
```

Therefore, having a class and an interface with the same name is equivalent to having two interfaces with the same name, and you will get merge conflicts if both instances of the interface re-declare the same members with different types.

Strangely enough, Typescript will allow for this:

```
export interface Foo {
    readonly x: number;
}

export class Foo {
    readonly x: number = 3;
}
```

but it won't allow `get x() { return 3; }` even though both of those generate as `readonly x: number`, so I can only imagine that the type checker considers them as different during merging even though they are semantically the same (this is why you can extend the interface and specify the readonly property as a getter function).

Comment: Thanks. Have posted an issue to get some clarification on why the compiler complains in this way: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14882

Comment: @NathanRidley The "response" you received to your question was unfortunate and doesn't reflect well on the typescript team.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation specific to accessors, and so far the Typescript team appears [unwilling to comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14882) on the issue.

```
class Foo {
  readonly x: number = 0;
}

class Bar extends Foo {}
interface Bar {
  readonly x: 2;
}

const bar = new Bar();
bar.x; // type is 2, no error
```

The team *has* [commented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3745#issuecomment-118924225) that "[w]hether a property is implemented as a field or a getter/setter pair is an implementation detail, not part of the type," but this is clearly not the case as of Typescript 4.2:

```
class Baz extends Foo {
    // error: "'x' is defined as a property in class 'Foo',
    //         but is overridden here in 'Baz' as an accessor."
    get x() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

I have no explanation for the team's responses. The comment that getters/setters are not part of the type system is from 2015 and may simply be outdated.

Comment: TS4.3 beta now lets you add getters and setters to interfaces. Perhaps this is now revealing how internally they’re represented differently.