# How to centralize interface initialization in React project with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, initialization, factory-pattern

I have a `React` project in `Typescript` and in many of my components I use an interface inside the `State`:

```
interface Item {
    selectedValue: string
    originalSelectedValue: string
    loading: boolean
    disabled: boolean
    isValid?: boolean
}

interface State {
   itemInstance: Item
}
```

In every component I use the `constructor` in order to initialize the instance of the interface:

```
constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        let itemInstance: Item = {
             selectedValue: '',
             originalSelectedValue: '',
             loading: true,
             disabled: false,
             isValid?: false
        };

        this.state = {
           itemInstance: itemInstance
        }
}
```

Since I need to repeat this initialization for every component, instead of copy/pasting the code in every component I was tryign to find a way to centralize the initialization. Since the interface cannot have implementation, I thought to implement some sort of **Factory Method Pattern** without usign a class:

```
     export const getItemInstance = (): Item  => {
        return ({
                 selectedValue: '',
                 originalSelectedValue: '',
                 loading: true,
                 disabled: false,
                 isValid?: false
       });
    }
```

Although I am not really keen on this solution, since for every Interface I need to create another file/component that implements the initialization. Does anybody know a pattern to implement this behaviour in `Typescript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you mentioned you don't want to use class but I'd probably just introduce a class implementing the interface anyway. Then you just make an instance via one line:

```
interface IItem {
    selectedValue: string
    originalSelectedValue: string
    loading: boolean
    disabled: boolean
    isValid?: boolean
}

class DefaultItem implements IItem {
  constructor(
    public selectedValue = '',
    public originalSelectedValue = '',
    public loading = true,
    public disabled = false,
    public isValid = false
  ) {}
}
```

Then inside your component:

```
constructor(props: Props) {
  super(props);

  const itemInstance = new DefaultItem();

  this.state = {
    itemInstance
  };
}
```

Not only this reads much better but when you want to change a default value of one specific property for all instances, you do it in one place.

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t know how to achieve it by using a class, I never stated I didn’t want to use it. Sorry for the misunderstanding, your solution is a good one

Comment: Sorry I just misread "I thought to implement some sort of Factory Method Pattern without using a class", thought creating a class seems a blocker for you :-). Glad you're happy with the solution, thanks for accepting!

Comment: I just found out here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055682/relationship-between-a-typescript-class-and-an-interface-with-the-same-name?rq=1) that in Typescript Interfaces and Classes with the same name merge. Therefore instead of using "Default" as prefix I can also assign the same name

Comment: How to write interface Props{} what it should include from parent

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize using the simple line:

```
interface IInterface{
    first: number;
    second: string;
}
```

then

```
var ourObject = {} as IInterface
var ourObjectArray = [] as Array<IInterface>
```

**In your case bellow is full code:**

```
interface Item {
    selectedValue: string
    originalSelectedValue: string
    loading: boolean
    disabled: boolean
    isValid?: boolean
}

interface State {
   itemInstance: Item
}


constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           itemInstance: {} as Item
        }
}
```